# Android Programming - Retrieving a STRING value from a specific column in the SQLite DATABASE TABLE and passing it to a variable in JAVA

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sms

I want to know **how to pass a value that was retrieve from the Column *numbers* in my database class, which is the DBUser.java, and assign it to a variable to another class?**. 
I've tried this method in my DBUser.java:

```
public String getNumber() throws SQLException  
{  
    String number;
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NUMBER}, null, null, null, null, null);

    number = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER)); // KEY_NUMBER ="numbers"
    mCursor.close();

    return number; // I think I'm missing something here???? IDK
}
```

And this is the method in my main class which I would like to pass the value of the column *numbers*:

```
public void onACU (View view) {
    String messageToSend = "ACU ON";

    DBUser dbUser = new DBUser(AleccMainActivity.this);  
    dbUser.open();  // I opened the DB
    // recipient is a global variable.
    recipient = dbUser.getNumber();//then I assigned the method in my string var thinking that the value will be passed to it.
    dbUser.close(); // then i close the DB

    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(recipient, null, messageToSend, null,null);
}
```

My instincts tell me that my db.query and return statement doesn't seem right so please do tell me on how to get it working.
I'm new to java though. thanks!

Comment: And how exactly do we know what is right or wrong unless your tell us?

Comment: please post, what is the method returning instead of the desired number, and if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: One exception comes from not calling `mCursor.moveToFirst()`(or `moveToNext`) before using `getString()` on the `mCursor`.

Comment: I think moveToFirst() isn't necessary here cos my table has only 1 row.

Comment: The Cursor returned by a query has its internal position set to -1(attempting to get data from it when it's in this position will throw an exception, I hope you're not discarding the SQLiteException where you use the getNumber method). You need that call so you set the cursor for a valid position(and you should check for its size before attempting any data retrieval). Your question is ambiguous as you don't explain **what** is happening when you try your code.

Comment: its because you're just focusing on the code, not on my question.

Comment: clearly, there's something wrong with my code. AND I just wanna know **HOW TO RETRIEVE A VALUE FROM A DB(SQLITE) THEN ASSIGN IT TO A SPECIFIC VARIABLE FROM ANOTHER CLASS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the cursor has only one row, you have to call moveToFirst() or moveToNext().

Comment: ok. supposed I added the `moveToFirst()`, now what? does the `moveToFirst()`/`moveToNext()` help when assigning the data I want to retrieve from the database to the variable in the other class?

Comment: This line will return you the number you want :
number = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER));